# Concatenation of a infinite language and a finite language

Tags: theory, computation-theory

Why is it that the concatenation of a infinite language and a finite language always finite iff the language is not the empty set? I thought concatenating an infinite language with the empty set would just be the infinite language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "The concatenation of a infinite language and a finite language always finite" -- where did you read this??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formal language theory, which is more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is false. Try concatenating Σ* and Σ. This gives back Σ<sup>+</sup>, which is infinite.

I think that you meant

> The concatenation of an infinite language I and a finite language F is **infinite** iff F ≠ ∅

This statement is true. If F = ∅ then IF is the empty set because the concatenation of any language and the empty language is the empty language. Specifically, IF = { wx | w in I and x in F }, so if F is empty, there are no x's that satisfy the condition x in F.

On the other hand, if x ≠ ∅ we can prove that IF is infinite. Consider any string w ∈ I whose length is longer than any string in F. Then the set wF = { wx | x in F } is infinite because there's at least one string in wF in-between any two multiples of |w|. Since wF ⊆ IF, this means that IF is infinite.

Hope this helps!